# iCloud Key Value Sync - first launch

Tags: cocoa-touch, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore, mkicloudsync

I am using iCloud to store sync user preferences between devices. On the device, these are stored in an array of 'Favorite Teams' in `NSUserDefaults`, and I am using [MKiCloudSync](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKiCloudSync) to mirror them to the `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. Changes on one device are propagating to the second device well.

But I am not sure how to prevent the cloud data from being wiped on the first launch after a new install. Here is what's happening:

1. Device A launches for the first time. App finds nothing in the cloud. User adds multiple items to the array in NSUserDefaults. Changes are synced immediately to cloud.
2. Device B launches for the first time, but is offline. User adds a single item to the `NSUserDefaults` array, then remembers the app supports iCloud, so finds some wifi instead.
3. Device B pushes its version of the defaults to the cloud (with only one item). Device A pulls it, effectively wiping out all of the teams added on Device A.

Is this a limitation of iCloud or is my implementation naive? The docs address a similar issue where a 'highest level' is synced, and adds application logic to never overwrite this value with a smaller value. That's fine when there is some clear business logic to adhere to (higher level is always the one to keep), but when data is more arbitrary, I don't see how I can determine what to do.

Or is it because I am using an array in NSUserDefaults for 'Favorite Teams' and replacing it wholesale? If I used separate keys for each team, perhaps they will be synced independently, based on time code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you sync a value for a specific key, you run the risk that it will be changed by a different device using the same account. The iCloud service chooses the winning value for you, makes updates, and notifies you when it's done. This is a limitation of iCloud and of your app, and is a simple example of why syncing is hard. What if your step 2 above looked like this:

> Device B launches for the first time, and iCloud is available. The app downloads the current data from device A. The user changes their mind and deletes all the data they created on device A. Then they a single new item.

Well, what then? Step 3 still happens exactly as you describe it, except that this time the incoming data is what the user wants. You could refactor your data but the same kind of situation will still be possible.

One option is to keep a non-syncing local copy of the data, so that you can compare incoming changes with the previous local state. What to do when they're different is up to you. Just don't forget that even dramatic changes might well be exactly what the user wants, and not a syncing issue that needs to be fixed. Or, they might be something that would lose data the user wants to keep. Resolving this conflict is your job.